# Can I make generic constuctor for different List<> In Java?

Tags: java, generics

I have a Function in a Class where I have declared `List<A>,List<B>,List<C>........` to 1000 of list each of them in separate For loop.

I have initialized the cacheMetaDataList to put all the data:

```
 List<CacheMetaData> cacheMetaDataList=new ArrayList<>();
```

I am adding all the data of For loop in :

```
cacheMetaDataList.add(new CacheMetaData(key,size,value));
```

CacheMetaDataImpl.java class

```
  public List<CacheMetaData> getAllCacheName(){
        List<CacheMetaData> cacheMetaDataList=new ArrayList<>();
        for( Cache.Entry<String, GenericClassForList> entry : this.operatingParametersCache) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            List<A> value = entry.getValue();
            int size=value.size();
            cacheMetaDataList.add(new CacheMetaData(key,size,value));
        }

        for( Cache.Entry<String, GenericClassForList> entry : this.securitiesTradingParameterCache) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            List<B> value = entry.getValue();
            int size=value.size();
            cacheMetaDataList.add(new CacheMetaData(key,size,value));
        }

        for( Cache.Entry<String, GenericClassForList> entry : this.marketCloseStatisticsCache) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            List<C> value = entry.getValue();
            int size=value.size();
            cacheMetaDataList.add(new CacheMetaData(key,size,value));
        }

        return cacheMetaDataList;
    }
```

The problem is not in this class but the problem starts with this class:

```
package com.cache.model;

import com.tms.component.securitiestradingparams.entity.SecuritiesTradingParamDTO;

import java.util.List;

public class CacheMetaData {

    private String cacheName;
    private int count;
    private List<A> aList;
     private List<B> bList;
      private List<C> cList;



    public CacheMetaData(String cacheName, int count,List<A> a) {
        this.cacheName = cacheName;
        this.count = count;
        tlis.aList=a;
    }

    public CacheMetaData(String cacheName, int count,List<A> b) {
        this.cacheName = cacheName;
        this.count = count;
        tlis.bList=b;
    }



    public CacheMetaData(String cacheName, int count,List<A> c) {
        this.cacheName = cacheName;
        this.count = count;
        tlis.cList=c;
    }

}
```

What I got problem in the class is for every  `new CacheMetaData(key,size,value);` .Suppose if there are 1000 of list then I need to make 1000 of constructor. I need a generic constructor which can initialize the different list of objects.It will be very boiler code to make 1000 of constructors for different list.

Comment: What are A, B,etc., supposed to be in your List<A>, List<B> use, such that there are 1000 of them?

Comment: yes there will be like 1000 of different list

Comment: Use List<Object> instead of explicit List<A>, List<B>, etc.

Comment: i am prohibited to use List<Object> , is there any other good generic technique?

Comment: In all the Constructors you have passed List<A>, I think it should be A, B and C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not you go for a generic one?

```
package com.cache.model;

import com.tms.component.securitiestradingparams.entity.SecuritiesTradingParamDTO;

import java.util.List;

public class CacheMetaData<CACHE> {

    private String cacheName;
    private int count;
    private List<CACHE> cache;

    public CacheMetaData(String cacheName, int count,List<CACHE> cache) {
        this.cacheName = cacheName;
        this.count = count;
        tlis.cache = cache;
    }
```

So at the CacheMetaDataImpl.java class

```
  public List<CacheMetaData> getAllCacheName(){
        List<CacheMetaData> cacheMetaDataList=new ArrayList<>();
        for( Cache.Entry<String, GenericClassForList> entry : this.operatingParametersCache) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            List<operatingParametersCache> value = entry.getValue();
            int size=value.size();
            cacheMetaDataList.add(new CacheMetaData<operatingParametersCache>(key,size,value));
        }

        for( Cache.Entry<String, GenericClassForList> entry : this.securitiesTradingParameterCache) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            List<securitiesTradingParameterCache> value = entry.getValue();
            int size=value.size();
            cacheMetaDataList.add(new CacheMetaData<securitiesTradingParameterCache>(key,size,value));
        }

        for( Cache.Entry<String, GenericClassForList> entry : this.marketCloseStatisticsCache) {
            String key = entry.getKey();
            List<marketCloseStatisticsCache> value = entry.getValue();
            int size=value.size();
            cacheMetaDataList.add(new CacheMetaData<marketCloseStatisticsCache>(key,size,value));
        }

        return cacheMetaDataList;
    }
```